# How to cleanup docker containers and images on linux machines

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, redhat, docker-machine

We have Linux redhat machine with docker and docker compose

Now we want to clean all containers and images - like we have scratch new docker

As I understand to get that , we need to perform the following procedure with this order:

Am I right with this procedure? , or I missing something?

```
 1. docker stop <CONTAINER ID>
 2. docker container rm <CONTAINER ID>
 3. docker image rm  <IMAGE ID>
```

example

*first find - CONTAINER ID*

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
654fa81f4439        confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:5.0.0   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes        0.0.0.0:9021->9021/tcp                       control-center
```

1)

*stop container*

```
docker stop 654fa81f4439
654fa81f4439
```

2)

delete container

```
docker container rm 654fa81f4439
654fa81f4439
```

3)

*find image ID*

```
docker images
REPOSITORY                                  TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE

confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center   5.0.0               e0bd9a5edb95        15 months ago       617MB
```

*delete image*

```
ocker image rm  e0bd9a5edb95
Untagged: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:5.0.0
Untagged: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center@sha256:2e406ff8c6b1b8be6bf01ccdf68b14be0f0759db27c050dddce4b02ee0894127
Deleted: sha256:e0bd9a5edb9510a326934fa1a80a4875ab981c5007354de28f53bfb3e11bc34a
Deleted: sha256:c23255297f6d75f156baf963786d3ded1d045b726d74ed59c258dc8209bac078
Deleted: sha256:6cab492e72ca2578897b7ceecb196e728671158e262957f3c01e53fd42f6f8b4
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, yes, it is the correct procedure to clear all the containers and images.

But you can do it more easily. For example:

- Stop all containers [at
  once](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-remove-docker-images-containers-volumes-and-networks/#stop-and-remove-all-containers):
  `docker container stop $(docker container ls -aq)`
- Remove [all stopped](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_prune/) containers: `docker container prune --force`
- Remove [all unnused](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/) images: `docker image prune --all --force`

Sometimes [Docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) are used for containers to persist data. You may want to [clean them too](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_prune/) (`docker volume prune --force`).

---

Others Docker resources may be left on your system (such as networks and build caches).

You can appeal to `docker system prune` to [remove all unused data](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/):

> ```
> $ docker system prune --all --volumes
> WARNING! This will remove:
>         - all stopped containers
>         - all networks not used by at least one container
>         - all volumes not used by at least one container
>         - all images without at least one container associated to them
>         - all build cache
> Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
> ```